# How to force a UISearchControllers search bar to end "focused" state?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uisearchbar

Im running into a problem when I preform a search, I can't get the search bar to reset from it's focused state (The background view is dimmed and the cancel button is still in the search bar. I want to clear the search bar and NOT have the background dimmed).

The view controller has the following (in the view did load):

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search here"
searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

When I tap search, I get have the following:

```
  func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.endEditing(true)
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    searchBar.text = ""
    self.navigationItem.searchController?.resignFirstResponder()
  }
```

The `searchBar.endEditing(true)` doesn't seem to be doing anything. Nor the `resignFirstResponder`. The background of the view is still dimmed.

For reference, the view controller is embedded in a nav controller, which in part a tab bar view controller (if that matters). And after the search is made, I push another view controller on the stack (hence why I want to clear the search bar and reset it's state when the view controller is shown again).

I've added some pictures to show the problem visually. The second photo is what Im left with after search is pressed when I want to to reset and look like the first photo.

[image: Before Search]
[image: After Search]

Answer (score 0):

`self.navigationItem.searchController?.isActive = false` is apparently what I'm looking for